# Modifying an extension to include a script on static pages as well as product & category pages?

Tags: magento2, extensions, amasty

I've installed an extension that includes a script on product and category pages. I'm trying to get the script to load on static content pages as well. I've been digging through the source code of the extension and thought that I found the spot where it's determined whether or not to load the script but haven't had any luck.

The extension contains a `view/frontend/templates/config.phtml` file that has the following:

```
<?php if ($block->isAjaxAdd()): ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    <?= /* @noEscape */
        $helper->encode(
            [
                "#product_addtocart_form:not([amcart-observed]), form[data-role=\"tocart-form\"]:not([amcart-observed]), .action.tocart:not([amcart-observed])" => [
                    'Amasty_Cart/js/amcart' => $amcartParams
                ]
            ]
        );
    ?>
    </script>
```

The `isAjaxAdd` method looks like this:

```
public function isAjaxAdd()
{
        return ($this->getPageType() == self::PRODUCT_PAGE && $this->getHelper()->isUsedOnProductPage())
            || $this->getPageType() == self::CATEGORY_PAGE;
}
```

I've attempted to just comment all of this code out and `return true` on the method but the script is still not loaded on normal pages.

I've also just tried to echo something out on this phtml template before the `$block->isAjaxAdd()` call, but it still only shows on category and product pages.

Is there another place that I'm missing that would only load this template on product/category pages?

Comment: I think phtml is added only product and category pages using xml. if you want it be available on all pages, you need to add  `config.phtml` in default.xml

Comment: I don't see a default.xml file in the extension, but I do see in the `/etc/` folder with: `acl.xml, config.xml, di.xml, module.xml, view.xml`.

Comment: The `isAjaxAdd` method is inside of a class that extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and sets the template like this: `$this->setTemplate('Amasty_Cart::config.phtml');`

Comment: you need to create that, make a copy of catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any catalog_product_view.xml file in this extension